# FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: android

I am new in Android development, I have a frames extraction application at a given frequency. I can extract 80 frames in total but beyond that I get this error in the debugger and the app crash.
i need to extract at least 800 frames i need help please here is my code

```
   public void extractionFrame(final File file) throws IOException, JCodecException {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bArray = new ArrayList<>();

    final ArrayList<Integer> rouge = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Integer> vert = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Integer> bleu = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tabColor = new ArrayList<>();

    if (file != null) {
        if (file.exists()) {

            final String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            final int nbrFrame = 200;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                progressDialog.setMessage("chargement");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setTitle("please wait");
                progressDialog.show();
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        ArrayList rgb = new ArrayList();
                        int looper = 340000;
                        for (int i = 0; i < nbrFrame; i++) {

                            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
                            mmr.setDataSource(path);
                            Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(looper, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST); 
                            rgb = extractRGB(b);
                            rouge.add((Integer) rgb.get(0));
                            vert.add((Integer) rgb.get(1));
                            bleu.add((Integer) rgb.get(2));

                            tabColor.add(rouge);
                            tabColor.add(vert);
                            tabColor.add(bleu);
                            rgb.clear();

                            mmr.release();
                            System.out.println("je suis le nombre de bitmap   " + b + i);
                            looper += 34000;
                        }
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            saveList(tabColor, getContext());
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                };
                thread.start();
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access these:

```
rouge.add((Integer) rgb.get(0));
vert.add((Integer) rgb.get(1));
bleu.add((Integer) rgb.get(2));
```

While your rgb array is empty.

Clearly

```
rgb = extractRGB(b);
```

is not working. You should check if it returned anything at all. Like so:

```
if (!rgb.isEmpty()) {
    rouge.add((Integer) rgb.get(0));
    vert.add((Integer) rgb.get(1));
    bleu.add((Integer) rgb.get(2));
} else {
    Log.e("tag", "ERROR: RGB array is empty");
}
```

Or something like that.

Also, it is easier to help you if you post your Stack Trace.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: thank u a lot Luis Henriques for your help the problem due to indexOutOfBoundsException is solved but 
it always returns " ERROR: RGB array is empty" when the frame number exceeds 80 I don't know why. the video is long enough to have even 1000 frames.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that. We need more information. Why don't you open a new question and mention which library you are using and expose the code of that  extractRGB() function? Maybe there's something wrong within it.